# Source of Whitespace Within `<html>` Element at Bottom of Basic Webpage

Tags: html, css

Could anyone shed some light upon the source of the 8px whitespace at the bottom of the  element box when inspected with DevTools?

```css
/* No stylesheet - all CSS from DevTools on Chrome user agent stylesheet */

element.style {}

html {
  display: block;
}

head {
display: none;
}

body {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <p>Hello, world</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Highlighting the `<html>` element box with DevTools shows its vertical dimension to be 189px:

[image: Highlighted <html> element Box]

[image: Devtools View]

Whilst from DevTools, the highlighted `<body>` element box has a total vertical dimension of 181px (including  margins).

[image: Highlighted <body> element Box]

[image: Devtools View]

Why does the `<html>` element box extend down by 8px beyond the `<body>` element box at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Issue is now resolved. 

The extra whitespace was not caused by the default `<body>` element margin settings, but instead by the default user agent stylesheet margin settings on the `<p>` element (as can be seen in my posted codesnippet). Hence, setting body margins to 0 would not have solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

> Browsers come with a surprising amount of CSS by default, which we call user-agent stylesheets. These styles are the reason that, without any CSS on our part, an <h1> is bigger than an <h2>, **and why the <body> has a margin on it that we tend to always remove.**
> a

Like [Kevin Powell writes on freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-margins/), it's quite normal to the following at the start of a new project.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that jna. 

I can understand the default margins for the `<body>` element. I'm just not sure I understand why there is whitespace within the `<html>` element box at the bottom only, below the limits of the lowermost `<body>` element margin.

Comment: It assume it has to do with collapsing margins. It's probably the margins on your <p> doing it

Answer (score -2):

Its called default margin set by the browser . If you want to reset everything to zero you can use

> `*{margin:0; padding:0;}`

Comment: No need to do this for every element. 
body { margin: 0 } should be sufficient.

Comment: This is a heavy-handed strategy that can have negative consequences on many elements.